# ! Undefined control sequence. minipage graphic

Tags: beamer, graphics

I am trying to add two minipages beside each other in Latex beamer and I am getting the error `! Undefined control sequence.`

I appreciate any help.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx} %  30.05  13:01 adedd [demo]
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, shadows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\newcommand{\twoobjects}[2]{%
  \centering \leavevmode\vbox{\hbox{#1}\nointerlineskip\hbox{#2}} %
}

\usecolortheme[named=Maroon]{structure}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]
\title{Test Test}
\author{Test Test}
\institute{Test Test}
\date{11.02.15}
\usepackage{float}
\begin{document}



\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Related Projects}

\begin{block}{Test Test}

Test Test Test Test

\begin{itemize}
\item Test, Test, Test,...
\end{itemize}

\end{block}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth, height=360px]{img/moovit_2}
  \captionof{figure}{Moovit map modes}
  \label{fig:test1}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth, height=360px]{img/moovit_4}
  \captionof{figure}{Moovit route monitoring}
  \label{fig:test2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{capt-of}` should do. But you can quite savely use normal `figure`-environments as floating is deactivated in beamer.

Comment: Is there any way to put one caption for the both minipages? Not separated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command `\captionof` is provided by packages like `capt-of`, `caption` or any `KOMA`-class. It is useful if you want to give a caption in a non-floating environment, which can be useful at times.

Here, we have a `beamer` case. Floating is disabled in beamer, the user is solely responsible that suff is fitting on the frame. You are using package `float` along  with the `H` placement specifier, which would again disable the floating.

You were using `minipage`s to align the graphics, and give two separate captions. You don't need `captionof` though.

If you want to have a single caption for both figures, no problem as well `:-)`

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\begin{document}



\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Related Projects}
    \begin{figure}%[H]
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth, height=36px]{example-image}
            \caption{Moovit map modes}
            \label{fig:test1}
        \end{minipage}%
        \begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth, height=36px]{example-image}
            \captionof{figure}{Moovit route monitoring}
            \label{fig:test2}
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}%[H]
        \centering
            \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth,
            height=36px]{example-image}\hfill%
            \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth, height=36px]{example-image}
            \caption{A caption for both images}
    \end{figure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: eanUndefinedMinipage.]

In general, a presentation is a visual/oral thing. Any text should aid the speaker. In my opinion, it is best just to say what is in the picture: «And here you can see the platypus doing the jazz dance«.

Comment: You are right I will do it as u recommended ;)

Comment: @ocean You may later decide to put your presentation in an article (keyword `beamerarticle`), maybe keeping the captions might be a good idea (and just print them in case of putting it into an article `\mode<article>`).